# Has anyone built a program slicer in Java?

Tags: java, slice

I have to build a program slicer in java to slice source code based on a slicing criterion. I see there are a very few libraries out there for this purpose. Notwithstanding, I would like to try this myself. I have read some publications on the topic that include the use of a dependence graph to work out the data and control dependencies in a program. A slicing algorithm can then be used in conjunction with a slicing criterion to generate slices of the java program. Has anyone done this type of thing before? If so, could you perhaps point me in the right direction to get started with this? I have searched and search and cannot figure out where to start, what APIs exist (if any).

An Example would be:

```
public class Foo {
   public void fooBar() {
      int x = 10;
      int y = 12; 
      String s = "";
      for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
         s += x;
         x++;
         y += 3;
      }
      System.out.println("y value " + y);
   }
}
```

If a slicing criterion (13, y) is choosen, where 13 is the last line in the above code, then the result will be

```
public class Foo {
   public void fooBar() {
      int y = 12;
      for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
         y += 3;
      }
   }
}
```

The slicing criterion returns all of the statements that may affect variable 'y' at line 13.

Comment: Do you have any reference to an existing commercial or free program slicer? I don't really know what you want the software to do. Maybe some source code slicing examples by hand?

Comment: What is a 'slice' of a Java program?

Comment: I looked at indus (http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu). @Jon, see here for program slicing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing)

Comment: @Joeblackdev: ("Have to build?") Yes, you need dependence graphs; to do this well, you need local and global dependences, and yes people have built slicers (see www.grammmatech.com CodeSurfer). I think you've found the key Java implementation. I don't know that a lot of work has been done on it for several years.

Comment: Please add some samples to give people an idea of what you want to do.

Comment: @Jon/Thorbjorn:  See wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing

Comment: I've added an example of what program slicing does.

Answer (score 2):

There is very less work in this area. You can reuse code  of some open source utility like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) or [yasca](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Then you can apply your own implementation logic for the slicing.

Answer (score 2):

Late, but maybe useful for others: [Wala](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Slicer). WALA includes a slicer, based on context-sensitive tabulation of reachability in the system dependence graph.